# Move Work Items to different project on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to move/copy my Work Items into a different project. I will need all the Epics, Features, User stories, Tasks, comments, links etc.

[The steps given here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azdevops&tabs=new-nav#move-a-work-item-to-another-project) show how to move a single work item, so my plan is to move my Epics which were only a handful and not have to move each and every user story/task. But unfortunately when the Epic is moved, the children are left behind.

Is there any other way to do this?

[I saw this Excel solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azdevops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts), but doesn't look like its copying the comments.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You may use a bulk move:

1. Create new query to select your work items [Create and save managed queries with the query editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azdevops&tabs=new-nav):
   [image]
2. Select all work items in the query result and select move:
   [image]
3. Select your new team project:
   [image]
4. Save all work items:
   [image]

Comment: if you have experience with c# you may try this example: [Azure DevOps Rest Api Move Work items](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/01/29/azure-devops-services-rest-api-11-move-work-items-to-another-team-project/)

Comment: Thank you this was perfect! Jist one thing, I was not able to see the results in 'Tree View' as the docs suggested.

Comment: If you about manual moving through a query: it supports tree view. If you about c# example: yes it does not support tree view and if it is still actual I can update that example for tree view.

Comment: @Gadam can you please tell us if you had back the tree view or if it is still bug thnaks

Comment: You can migrate work items directly from the backlog also.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but it didn't move the associated repo files from old to new project.

Comment: Moves to a different project always seem to reset the state of the work item to New.  This is clearly not what we want.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is only on VSTS ? I can't find this menu on Devops on premise...

Comment: @k4st0r42 I did not check it on-premise, but the documentation says it is supported by `Azure DevOps Server 2022 - Azure DevOps Server 2019 | TFS 2018` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops

Comment: I finally did it by editing the parent link

Comment: Perfect, saved me a lot of work! Thanks!