# DevOps: Copy kanban board to another organization

Tags: azure-devops

I work on Azure DevOps in few organization. I was looking for a way to move/copy kanban board to another project or organization. I found one way:
 [Azure Boards Kanban Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alm-devops-rangers.KanbanBoardTools) but it doesn't work properly.

How i can do it?

Comment: I am interested in what you mean by: doesn't work properly. It tends to do what it was designed to do, but I can see how that's too limited for this scope.

Comment: @jessehouwing thanks for your comment. I made a mistake. I meant that this add-on doesn't allow to copy an array between organizations but enables between teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DevOps: Copy kanban board to another organization

There is no such out of box way to copy kanban board to another organization.

With built-in solution, we could only move the work items into a different project in the same organization.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411979/move-work-items-to-different-project-on-azure-devops) for some details.

After those work items move to the another project, they will appear in kanban board.

If you want to copy kanban board to another **organization**, you could use the Excel to achieve it:

Ticket here: [How do I move Work Items from one organization to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621967/how-do-i-move-work-items-from-one-organization-to-another)

Besides, the extension Azure Boards Kanban Tools is used to allows teams to either grab settings from another team and apply them to their boards or to allow a team to copy their settings to **another team**. For the extension, you can refer to [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration), which allow you to migrate Teams, Work Items, and Plans & Suits from one Project to another in Azure DevOps/TFS both within the same Organisation, and between Organisations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that the only way to use the same settings (columns, pools) on the board in other projects and organizations is to create them from scratch?

Comment: @AdrianK, You could try to use the Excel, check the second link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks you. I will check this.